# On paushig and resuming CountDownTimer providing some unwanted behaviour, making my progress bar negative count

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

**MainActivity Code**

```
package com.example.need7minute


class ExerciseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityExerciseBinding

    //rest time
    private var resTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
    private var restProgress = 0

    //exercise timer
    private var exerciseTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
    private var exerciseProgress = 0


    //exercises
    private var exerciseList: ArrayList<ExerciseModel>? = null
    private var currentExercisePosition = -1
    private var remainingTime:Long?=null
    private var totalTime:Long=10000
    private var isPushed:Boolean=false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityExerciseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //To set the toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolBarExcersise)
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        }
        binding.toolBarExcersise.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
        exerciseList = Constants.defaultExerciseList()
        //call the set progress bar
        setRestView()
    }

    //set the ready timer
    private fun setRestView() {
        binding.restView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.restTxt.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.tvExerciseName.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.exerciseLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.animBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.animationView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        if (resTimer != null) {
            resTimer?.cancel()
            restProgress = 0
        }
        setRestProgressBar()
    }

    //set the exercise timer
    private fun setExerciseView() {
        binding.restView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.restTxt.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.tvExerciseName.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.exerciseLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.animBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.animationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE


        if (exerciseTimer != null) {
            exerciseTimer?.cancel()
            exerciseProgress = 0
        }
        binding.animationView.setAnimation(exerciseList!![currentExercisePosition].getAnimName())
        binding.animationView.playAnimation()
        binding.tvExerciseName.text = exerciseList!![currentExercisePosition].getExName()
        setExerciseProgressBar(totalTime)

    }

    //setting the progressbar
    private fun setRestProgressBar() {
        binding.progressBar.progress = restProgress
        resTimer = object : CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                restProgress++
                binding.progressBar.progress = 2 - restProgress
                binding.timerTxt.text = (2 - restProgress).toString()
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                currentExercisePosition++
                setExerciseView()
            }

        }.start()
    }
```

**//setting the progressbar and title for upcoming exercise**

```
    private fun setExerciseProgressBar(Time:Long) {
        binding.exerciseProgressBar.progress = exerciseProgress
        exerciseTimer = object : CountDownTimer(Time, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                binding.animBtn.setOnClickListener {
                    if(binding.animBtn.text=="PAUSE"){
                        remainingTime=millisUntilFinished
                        pauseExercise()
                        binding.animBtn.text="RESUME"
                    }
                    else{
                        resumeExercise()
                        binding.animBtn.text="PAUSE"
                    }
                }
                Log.i("timeGOne","$millisUntilFinished")
                exerciseProgress++
                binding.exerciseProgressBar.progress = 10 - exerciseProgress
                binding.exerciseTimerTxt.text = (10 - exerciseProgress).toString()

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                Snackbar.make(
                    binding.exAcitvity,
                    "The 30sec for this exercise is over.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                if (currentExercisePosition < exerciseList?.size!! - 1)
                    setRestView()
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@ExerciseActivity, "Done all exercises!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }

        }.start()
    }
```

**//Pausing exercise**

```
    private fun pauseExercise(){
        exerciseTimer!!.cancel()
        binding.animationView.pauseAnimation()
        Log.i("time_remain","$remainingTime")
        Log.i("pg","$exerciseProgress")
    }
```

**//resuming Timer**

```
    private fun resumeExercise(){
        setExerciseProgressBar(remainingTime!!)
        binding.animationView.resumeAnimation()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (resTimer != null) {
            resTimer?.cancel()
            restProgress = 0
        }
        if (exerciseTimer != null) {
            exerciseTimer?.cancel()
            exerciseProgress = 0
            totalTime=10000
            remainingTime=null
        }
//        binding = null
    }
}


**//wrong or error part**
```

[App's Screen shot the error part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnT8o.jpg)

In this picture the value of progress is negative (-2) ,, as i have paushed & resumed the timer 2 times so the timer ends at -2 progress , thats the wrong i ma getting ,, i am unable to fix it ,, someone please help me out to fix it. I have tried many techniques but unable to fix the issue of negative countdown of progress bar.

The main three functions are bolded , where one is the starting of the countdown and other two is for pause and resume the count down.

If i have done some wrong please mention , or give some source code so that i can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of code to go through so I don't know exactly what your issues are. I noticed a few weird things, like you don't seem to create a new timer in your resume function, so how will your timer keep going?

Another issue is trying to count progress by incrementing an integer. That is quite error prone if anything gets out of sync. It probably introduces error every once in a while under various different events, including when you stop and start timers. Instead, you can recalculate this value on each tick using the remaining time.

To reduce losing precision after multiple pauses and resumes, you can use a smaller interval. Having the extra `onTick` calls fire is no problem since you're doing trivial updates there.

I suggest you create a separate class to manage your timer behavior (starting, pausing, resuming, updating progress bar) to help keep that code consolidated and easier to manage. Also, it will reduce code duplication because you have two timers. Here's a possible example:

```
class PausableTimer(
    /** Duration of timer. Used the next time it is started. */
    val timerDurationMillis: Long,
    /** Optional ProgressBar to update while the timer is running. */
    var progressBar: ProgressBar? = null,
    /** Action to complete on each update. Also called with a value of 0 when the timer finishes. */
    var onTickListener: (millisLeft: Long)->Unit = {}
) {
    private var timer: Timer? = null

    inner class Timer(var remainingTimeMillis: Long): CountDownTimer(timerDurationMillis, INTERVAL) {

        init {
            update(remainingTimeMillis)
            start()
        }
        
        private fun update(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            progressBar?.apply {
                progress = (millisUntilFinished.toFloat() / timerDurationMillis.toFloat() * (max - min) + min).roundToInt()
            }
            remainingTimeMillis = millisUntilFinished
            onTickListener(millisUntilFinished)
        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) = update(millisUntilFinished)

        override fun onFinish() = update(0L)
    }

    fun start() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = Timer(timerDurationMillis)
    }

    fun pause() {
        timer?.cancel()
    }

    fun resume() {
        val oldTimer = timer
        if (oldTimer != null && oldTimer.remainingTimeMillis > 0L) {
            oldTimer.cancel() // in case pause() was not called
            timer = Timer(oldTimer.remainingTimeMillis - oldTimer.remainingTimeMillis % INTERVAL)
        } else {
            start()
        }
    }

    fun cancel() {
        timer?.cancel()
        timer = null
    }

    companion object {
        private const val INTERVAL = 100L
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity class, you can replace `resTimer`, `restProgress`, `exercisetimer`, `exerciseProgress`, `remainingTime`, and `totalTime` with:

```
private val restTimer = PausableTimer()
private val exerciseTimer = PausableTimer()
```

and then for example:

```
private fun setRestProgressBar() {
    restTimer.apply {
        timerDurationMillis = 2000L
        progressBar = binding.progressBar
        onTickListener = { millisUntilFinished ->
            binding.timerTxt.text = (millisUntilFinished  / 1000L).toString()
            if (millisUntilFinished == 0) {
                currentExercisePosition++
                setExerciseView()
            }
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

And you can call `pause()` and `resume()` on the `restTimer` at appropriate times.